# Treating an exception in such way to return a message when username is duplicate

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to return an error message when the username is a duplicate in my DB, the username is set as unique in the db. I am using `phpmyadmin` for the db (basically mysql).

The error is telling me that I need to "create costant SQLErrorCode". I followed [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) to some degree. I can't figure it out. Have I missed an import? Is `getResultCode` for SQLite?

**UPDATE:**

```
`exceptie.getErrorCode() == SQLError.SQL_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE` Changed `getResultCode` to `GetErrorCode()` and changed `SQLErrorCode` to `SQLError`
```

when I run the code, it says `Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: SQL_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE cannot be resolved or is not a field`

First attempt:

```
catch (SQLException exceptie) {
    if (exceptie.getResultCode() == SQLErrorCode.SQL_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE) {
        System.out.println("Numele de utilizator introdus este deja folosit!");
    } else {
        exceptie.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

P.S Basically I have the username set as unique in the db, and when an username that already exists in the DB is introduced, I want to use that error to return a message that will inform the user that the username is already in use.

Comment: maybe `getErrorCode()` ??? Remember, code is 'vendor specyfic'

Comment: DId try it, and it tells me to modify from `SQLErrorCode` to `SQLError`, looks something like this `exceptie.getErrorCode() == SQLError.SQL_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE`, but now it wants me to rename `SQL_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE`, I click to auto rename it, but nothing happens

Comment: If i run it it says : `Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 SQL_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE cannot be resolved or is not a field` so i guess this is the issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`ER_DUP_ENTRY`** is the MySQL Error Name corresponding to the MySQL Error Number of JDBC for handling duplicate entries. So, try to get error code from exception using `getErrorCode()` and match it with defined error number like below:

```
catch (SQLException exceptie) {
    if (exceptie.getErrorCode() == MysqlErrorNumbers.ER_DUP_ENTRY) {
        System.out.println("Numele de utilizator introdus este deja folosit!");
    } else {
        exceptie.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```